# Split an element at whitespace in python 2

Tags: python, whitespace

I have a text dump of letters and numbers, and I want to filter out only valid credit card numbers (for class, I swear). I used

```
for item in content:
    nums.append(re.sub('[^0-9]', ' ', item))
```

to take out everything that isn't a number, so I have a list of elements that are numbers with white space in the middle. If I don't turn the non-int characters into spaces, the numbers end up concatenated so the lengths are wrong. I want to split each element into a new element at the whitespace.

Here's a screenshot of part of the Sample output, since I can't copy it without python turning every group of multiple spaces into a single space: https://gyazo.com/4db8b8b78be428c6b9ad7e2c552454af

I want to make a new element every time there is one or more spaces. I tried:

```
for item in nums:
    for char in item:
        char.split()
```

and

```
for item in nums:
    item.split()
```

but that ended up not changing anything.

Comment: as an aside, if any of that data in your screenshot has "valid" credit card numbers, do consider removing those numbers, just fyi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`split`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) doesn't mutate the string but returns a list of strings instead. If you call it without storing the result as in your example it won't do anything good. Just store the result of `split` to new list:

```
>>> nums = ['1231  34  42 432', '12 345345 7686', '234234  45646 435']
>>> result = []
>>> for item in nums:
...     result.extend(item.split())
...
>>> result
['1231', '34', '42', '432', '12', '345345', '7686', '234234', '45646', '435']
```

Alternatively you could use list comprehension to do the above on one line:

```
>>> [x for item in nums for x in item.split()]
['1231', '34', '42', '432', '12', '345345', '7686', '234234', '45646', '435']
```